# Doubt with Conditional Expected Value in different cases

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, expected-value

I suggest you some exercises where my doubt comes back.

A) The rain in a certain period is represented from a random variable $T$ distributed like a $\Gamma(30,5)$. If $T=t$, the number of umbrellas $N$ sold by a certain shop complies with a Poisson law of parameter $4t$. Find $\mathbb{E}[N]$.

B) Let the random vector $\binom{X}{Y}\sim N_{2}(\binom{0}{0},\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & \rho\\ 
\rho & 
1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr))$ and $Z=X+Y$, find $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Z)$.

C) Mark, during his career, played $N$ tournament with $N\sim \mathrm{Geo}(s)$. Assume that Mark, in every tournament, has has a probability $p$ to win the tournament, independently. Let $T$ the number of tournament wins. Find $\mathbb{E}[T]$.

---

Well. I know that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] \bigr] =\mathbb{E}[Y]$, but:

-for A) we have $\mathbb{E}[N]=\mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathbb{E}[N \mid T] \bigr] =4\mathbb{E}[T]= \ldots$

-for B) we have $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Z)= \ldots =\mathbb{E}[X^2Y]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]\mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] \bigr] =\mathbb{E}[X^2]\rho\mathbb{E}[X]= \ldots$

-for C) we have $\mathbb{E}[T]=\mathbb{E}\bigl[\mathbb{E}[T \mid N] \bigr] =p\mathbb{E}[N]= \ldots$

**Why, *formally*, do we have for A) $4$, for B) $\rho$ and for C) $p$?**

Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Answer (score 1):

- A) Observe that $\mathbb{E}\left[N\mid T=t\right]=\color{red}4t$ justifying
  $\mathbb{E}\left[N\mid T\right]=\color{red}4T$.
- B) $\mathsf{Cov}\left(X,Z\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(X,X+Y\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(X,X\right)+\mathsf{Cov}\left(X,Y\right)=\mathsf{Var}X+\mathsf{Cov}\left(X,Y\right)=1+\rho$
- C) Observe that $\mathbb{E}\left[T\mid N=n\right]=n\color{red}p$ justifying $\mathbb{E}\left[T\mid N\right]=N\color{red}p$.

I don't see your logic in the way you try to handle case B) and further hope that A) and C) are enough to understand the presence of the factors $\color{red}4$ and $\color{red}p$ respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The same problem is here. Let $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y|X\sim U(0,x)$. So, if using the integration by parts I obtain $\mathbb{E}[Y]=1/4$ (correct), why $\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{2}]$? Why show up $\frac{1}{2}$ all of sudden?

Comment: Under condition $X=x$ random variable has distribution $U(0,x)$ and consequently it has expectation $\frac12x$. In short: $\mathbb E[Y\mid X=x]=\frac12x$. This justifies the conclusion $\mathbb E[Y\mid X]=\frac12X$. Then: $$\mathbb E[Y]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[Y\mid X]]=\mathbb E\frac12X=\frac12\mathbb EX=\frac12\frac12=\frac14$$